# What is the combined standard deviation of Poisson photon shot noise and Gaussian read noise?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, noise

On various image sensor web sites (e.g., https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=10773, https://www.microscopyu.com/tutorials/ccd-signal-to-noise-ratio  you'll see something to the effect that image sensor noise can be described as a combination of constant Gaussian noise (e.g., read noise) and intensity dependent Poisson noise (e.g., photon shot noise). They then take the RMS of the standard deviation of Gaussian noise and Poisson noise to get the total standard deviation of noise.

I'm confused about how the units work out when you combine the standard deviations in that way. Specifically, the standard deviation of photon shot noise is the square root of the number of photons acquired over a time period. Or converting to electrons, the square root of some proportional number of electrons. The standard deviation of read noise is just some number of electrons.

So combining the two to find the total standard deviation, you end up adding electrons^2 to electrons.

Is there a units conversion constant assumed that is not typically called out?

Any assistance clarifying this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Counts are unitless. Note that standard deviations are in the units of the original variable. If counts had units, you couldn't have the standard deviation of a Poisson equal to the square root of the mean, since it would then have the wrong units. Since counts are unitless, this isn't an issue.

Comment: Yes, I had that thought (counts are unitless), but then it seems that when you are combining standard deviations of Gaussian and Poisson distributions you are combining a unitless quantity (the standard deviation of a Poisson distribution) with a quantity that has units (the standard deviation of a Gaussian).

Comment: The thing you're trying to compute noise for is photon counts, right? Or is it photon counts plus something that isn't a count? ... Reading more carefully, I think I see that it's noise added later into the process of obtaining a recorded value.

Comment: ... Once you have your counts entering a detector, that's being used as an input to another process. The instrument is turning counts into something that is not-counts (like voltages) and at that point it's *not* unit-free. You shouldn't just blithely add "noises" together, but consider what's happening with random variables and how they're being transformed at each step. If you follow that process through, nothing would be confusing. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... The counts are transformed into voltages (and are then not counts, they're presumably more-or-less proportional to counts but are in unit of voltage); the voltages are in turn transformed once more into digital readings. At each stage (there may be more in there, this is not my area), you need to think about *how, exactly* the transformations are occurring and into what. You can't just gloss over what's happening with changes of unit (and sometimes transformations with the same units, such as when voltages *here* are turned into voltages *there*) and hope sense will pop out the end.